# how to deploy my jboss servlets to GoDaddy and make it available to my Android client?

Tags: web-services, dns

I have my web application running in jboss on my pc, accessible only in localhost. I have seen in sites like godaddy, they talk about giving a domain name to your site.

My application only serves resources (it only contains servlets). It will only used to process the incoming data and send responses to my Android clients. So any domain name is fine, because no one will be visiting the domain from the browser.

- Where is the mapping actually done?
- Will I be able to use my pc itself as the server or will I have to deploy the application on godaddy's server?
- So what are the steps I should take to make this web application be accessible on the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a domain name.   Clients can contact your server by its IP address.

If you want it to be more user-friendly you need to get a domain name from a domain name provider (like godaddy) and also get it into a DNS server (like godaddy) with a pointer to the IP address of your server.  These are independent things, but frequently sold together.

If your IP address changes, you will need a dynamic update client to update the DNS server.  My server has a dynamic IP and the DNS provider is dyndns.org.

Comment: you are right for now I don't need a domain name. So does dyndns provide the dynamic update client also.

Comment: Yes.  http://dyn.com/support/clients/

Comment: I created an account in the dyndns and thenI downloaded the dynamic update client. But after I enter the username and password it says no hosts were found. Obviously I am doing something terribly wrong. Can you please tell me how to proceed after creating an account in dyndns?