# Using DynDNS to dynamically update your IP address

Tags: web-hosting, domains, web-development, server

In this [link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29083/how-to-deploy-my-jboss-servlets-to-godaddy-and-make-it-available-to-my-android-c#comment27962_29084) stark had suggested that I use IP address instead of a domain name. He had also suggested that, if your ip address changes dynamically then the dynamic update client will update the dns server. I have created an account in DynDns but am unable to understand its working. 
My requirement is I want to use `my machine` as the `server`. Now will DynDns be able to provide me with IP address. Right now the I am using usb device to connect to the internet. Each time I plug it in and connect. I am provided with a public Ip Address. The problem here is that this Ip address changes each time I connect.
 How will Dyn Dns solve my problem? I am stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynDNS provides you with a domain name. As long as the domain name always points to your IP address it will work.

The update client runs on your computer, and periodically checks your IP address. If it detects that your IP address has changed it updates your DynDNS account so that your domain points to your new IP address.

Because of this no matter what your IP address is your domain name should point to it. As long as the update client is running to detect when the IP address changes.

If you go with only an IP address, as mentioned in the post you linked to, you will need to change the IP address in whatever is connecting to the server every time your IP changes. it is usually much better to use a domain name, especially in cases where your IP address will always be changing.

DynDNS will provide you with a free domain name which can do what you need. You won't need to purchase anything from an ISP like GoDaddy.

**EDIT**
As pointed out in the comments DynDNS no longer offers a free service. However another site offering a similar service for free is: http://www.no-ip.com/

Comment: okay..What will dyndns charge me for if they provide a free domain name?

Comment: Unfortunately DynDNS no longer provide a free service - as of Dec 2011 I believe prices start at $20/yr.

Comment: w3d, thanks for the information. I have updated my answer to include a different provider of free dns services.

Comment: @w3d : Can I do every thing that Sherwin Flight has told in his answer about dyndns, in no-ip.com also. Like will it provide a dynamic update client. My machines ip address keeps changing. So I will need a client to detect this and map this IP address to the domain name. I am ready to spend money. I don't want any fancy domain names.

Comment: @Ashwin : Yes, as far as I know, both DynDNS and no-ip provide the same core functionality. Their primary goal is to solve the problem of a changing IP address. Both provide an update client to inform the service of your updated IP address. Note that the free services probably only offer a free **subdomain** of one of their already registered domain names - so it's not too fancy. (Note also that _some_ routers also support _some_ of these services, which does away with the need for the update client - _if_ you are always connected on the same LAN. Which, by the sounds of it, you might not be.)

Comment: All of the free services like this use a subdomain of some sort, but allow you to pay a fee to use a custom domain that you already own. But, you said this server was just for serving some resources anyways, so it shouldn't really matter about using one of their domain names. w3d, the router that I used to own allowed the settings you mentioned. It allowed you to pick from several dynamic DNS providers, including no-ip and DynDNS, and would keep your IP information updated. Ashwin, if using a router you should check to see if you have this feature before downloading the update client.

Comment: However, if you are not familiar with your router settings there is no problem with downloading the update client anyways, even if your router does support this.

Comment: @SherwinFlight : I don't own a router. I connected to the internet using a usb internet card. And each time I connect the public IP assigned to me changes.

Comment: http://www.no-ip.com/ is what you need, with their update client running on your computer.

Comment: @SherwinFlight : I searched no-ip.com. But I can't seem to find the option of free domain name(what ever domain they give) with dynamic dns. Can you please tell me where you saw that option?

Comment: You can find it here: http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html